# spring-data dynamic entity annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

I have an entity class to be used in spring-data persistence

```
@Persistent 
public class Foo{
  Bar bar;
}
```

Since we are switching between Couchbase and Aerospike persistence layers - this class is going to be used in both of them for some time. That is why I have these class in common maven module. Module structure looks like this

- persistence-common
- persistence-aero
- persistence-couch

My idea here is to have spring-data CouchbaseRepository and AerospikeRepository in corresponding modules both implementing Repository class from common

```
public interface Repository {
   save(Foo foo);
}
```

And I have one problem. I need my Foo.class to have expiry option which could be achieved by adding either `@org.springframework.data.aerospike.mapping.Document(expiration = ...)` annotation for 
aerospike or `@org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Document(expiryExpression = ...)` annotation for couchbase. And I don't want this annotations to be in common module. I need them to be added to Foo class dynamically, depending on which of the modules (couchbase or aerospike or both) are included in runtime.

Can I somehow achieve such flexibility?

Comment: Question, why you don't want to put the annotations in the common module?

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. Use an `interface` for your base model inside `persistence-common`.

```
public interface Foo {
   Bar getBar();
}
```

You can now implement it once for the `persistence-aero` module

```
@Document(expiration = 1000)
public class AerospikeFoo implements Foo {
   @Override
   public Bar getBar() { ... }
}
```

And once for `persistence-couch`

```
@Document(expiryExpression = "...")
public class CouchbaseFoo implements Foo {
   @Override
   public Bar getBar() { ... }
}
```

This will make clear their usage scope and intent.
You don't need to re-use `@Persistent`, as it's already inherited with `@Document`.

If they share some kind of functionality, create a `class` to delegate to, on the line of `PersistenceFooHelper`. Do not extend an `abstract class`.

Comment: @agav if you need to post a long text it is better if you edit the question. Unfortunately comments do not have great formatting

Comment: I want to use repository.save(document) without caring about underlying implementation. But with your approach I will need to do something like 
`if (aerospike) document = new AerospikeDocument()
else document = new CouchbaseDocumnet();
repository.save(document)`

Comment: @agav if you have two modules, `persistence-aero` and `persistence-couch` that means each works with its own models and repositories. You wouldn't need to differentiate like that. Encapsulate the instantation of each `*Foo` implementation inside its own module.